# Spring-Ajax samples needed

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

i have a web application that uses spring framework
and i want to use ajax in some pages (adding/deleting stuff from page,db without refreshing the whole page)

tutorials and samples are needed for such stuff

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Spring MVC may be what you are looking for. Here's a good summary of Ajax improvements in the latest version: http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/. This blog links to the sample code used, which you can download and run to see a good working example.

More comprehensive documentation can found here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html.

Comment: +1 for the link to that SpringSource blog post.   Spring MVC/JSON is a FAQ on SO and that's a great reference.